# how to display custom hierarchies in same visual?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas, ssas-tabular

I have a specific hierarchy that I have developed:

[image]

I was expecting it to be:

level 6

( )level11

( )( )Account description

level 3

( )Account description

But I get a different result (see below), why is it? how can I achieve my hierarchy? is it even possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Think about the column headers. What would it say if the first column was either Level6 or Level3? This would be confusing to the user.

The best option is to either get the data into one table where the headers make sense, or to use 2 visuals, one for each hierarchy.